# How to find which component is focused?

Tags: java, swing, focus, awt, focuslistener

Hey I have a panel class in which there are two panels, one of the panels have text field. I want to perform an action when it gets focused.
The panel is added on the main frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`FocusListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html), here is simple example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame{

    public TestFrame(){
        init();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        JTextField f1 = new JTextField(5);
        f1.addFocusListener(getFocusListener());
        add(f1,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(new JTextField(5),BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }


    private FocusListener getFocusListener() {
        return new FocusAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                super.focusGained(e);
                System.out.println("action");
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String... s){
        new TestFrame();
    }

}
```

Also `JFrame` has [`getFocusOwner()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#getFocusOwner%28%29) method.

Answer (score 1):

Use the api

```
JFrame.getFocusOwner()
```

This will return a reference to the component with focus

You ca also check....

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner()
```

To the modification, just add a FocusListener to your respective Component, and implement the interface to your particular acitons.

Answer (score 1):

There are visual clue that helps to know which component has the focus, such as an active cursor in a text field. To work with the `FocusListener` Interface and in order to listen’s the keyboards gaining or losing focus, the listener object created from class is need to registered with a component using the component’s `addFocusListener()` method. The two important method `focusGained(FocusEvent e)` and `void focusLost(FocusEvent e)` which helps to find which component is focused.

To know more about [What is FocusListener Interface and How it Works](http://programmingguide.org/what-is-focuslistener-interface-and-how-it-works/).